# Check if phonenumber equals, then update others

Tags: php, mysql

Im a newbie in PHP, and i didnt quite get this.

I want to check in the PHP file if the ** $id as input and id as input column ** is already in the database, if it does..
Then should update all the other values: longitude, latitude, timestamp

Here's my code: (Only important parts...)

```
file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" .   print_r($_GET, true));


// Performing SQL query
if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
$data = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);
$id = $data['id'];
$latitude = $data['latitude'];
$longitude = $data['longitude'];
$timestamp = $data['timestamp'];

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($id) , mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),  mysql_real_escape_string($latitude), mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp))  ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
echo "OK";

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly are you using the phone number as a filter?

Comment: where is phoneno in your question?

Comment: Oh excuse me, thats the $id as input and the id as field in mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logic will be like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from table_name where phonenumber = your_phone number");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    // your code for when phone number not present
}
else
{
   // your update query.
}
```

this is just logic. Use `Mysqli` OR `PDO` instead of `mysql`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single SQL request. You need to create a `UNIQUE` index on the `id` field if not done yet then complete your request like the following:

```
INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) 
    VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    longitude=VALUES(longitude),
    latitude=VALUES(latitude),
    timestamp=VALUES(timestamp)
```

Comment: $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    longitude=VALUES(longitude),
    latitude=VALUES(latitude),
    timestamp=VALUES(timestamp)", mysql_real_escape_string($id) , mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),  mysql_real_escape_string($latitude), mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp))
   ;

Like this ?

Comment: I didn't wrap it in the sprintf() but yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 first create sp like :
    CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_name`(IN `par1` INT, IN `par2` INT, IN `par3` Decimal)
    begin
      declare Rec_Count int ;   
    Proc:
      begin
         select count(*) into Rec_Count from  table UL where phoneno=par1;
       if(Rec_Count <= 0) then
         select '0' as success,'Phoneno is not found' as  response;
          leave Proc;
       end if;

        INSERT INTO locatie (col1,col2,...) VALUES (par1,par2,...);
        select '1' as success,'data successfully inserted.' as  response;
    end ;

    end

    ----------------
    then your code is :

  execute sp like from your code is :
$query="call sp_name(par1,par2,..);"
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```